# Evaluate constant value in Roslyn from expression initialization that references other file

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am using Roslyn and the following piece of code to get compile time values of all constants defined in a handpicked list of files, not necessarily bound together by a csproj or sln files:

```cs
compilation = CSharpCompilation
   .Create("HelloWorld")
   .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(string).Assembly.Location))
   // syntax trees are handpicked cs files containing the constants.
   .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree1, syntaxTree2);

var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree1, true);

foreach (var symbol in (await syntaxTree1.GetRootAsync()).DescendantNodes().OfType<VariableDeclaratorSyntax>())
{
   var keySymbol = (IFieldSymbol)semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(symbol);
   if (keySymbol.IsConst)
   {
      var value = keySymbol.ConstantValue.ToString(); // sometimes there is no value, see the rest of the question
      Console.WriteLine(value);
   }
}
```

This works fine for normal constants, but when there's a constant `a` in `syntaxTree1` initialized as

```cs
const int a = b;
```

where `b` is a constant declared and initialized in `syntaxTree2`, the call to `ConstantValue` returns no value, my guess is that it's because the constant is declared in a different file.

My question is, is there a simple way to get the value of the constant defined in this manner (referencing constants from different files in the initialization) or do I have to essentially emulate building AST myself?

Comment: You may want to ask your Compilation for diagnostics on the file that isn't working, i.e. the one that contains 'a'. Creating a single metadata reference in the way you're doing might simply be sufficiently broken and the compiler is just having to throw it's hands up and give up.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski thanks, this unveiled multiple compilation errors, I'll proceed with the investigation and update the question once I see if the references work